# animated zoom to location/map placemark when mapview opened iOS

Tags: ios6, mkmapview, zooming, mkcoordinateregion

I've seen it on other applications exmaple ios 6 starbucks, when my mapview is opened, I want it to show the region as the whole of UK/British isles, then I want it to zoom in to my specified location region points I have.

Updated Code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
[mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
[mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
[mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 54.5;
region.center.longitude = -3.5;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 10.0f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 10.0f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:NO];

[self performSelector:@selector(zoomInToMyLocation)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:2]; //will zoom in after 1.5 seconds
}

-(void)zoomInToMyLocation
{
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = 51.502729 ;
region.center.longitude = -0.071948;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.19f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.19f;
[mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

[mapView setDelegate:self];

[self performSelector:@selector(selectAnnotation)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:0.5]; //will zoom in after 0.5 seconds

}

-(void)selectAnnotation
{

DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Design Museum";
ann.subtitle = @"Camberwell, London";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapView addAnnotation:ann];

}
```

Dont know if its correct, because the error is this line

```
ann.coordinate = region.center;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to start with showing one region and then zoom in, you have to issue two or more `setRegion` calls because `setRegion` by itself doesn't let you control the *starting* region or the speed of the animation.

In `viewDidLoad`, set the initial region's `span` so the entire UK is visible (try deltas of `10.0` instead of `0.15`).  You could also set `animated` to `NO` for the initial region.

Then before the end of `viewDidLoad`, schedule the zoom-in to be executed a few seconds later:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...

    [self performSelector:@selector(zoomInToMyLocation) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:5]; //will zoom in after 5 seconds
}
```

The `zoomInToMyLocation` method might look like this:

```
-(void)zoomInToMyLocation
{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
    region.center.latitude = 51.502729 ;
    region.center.longitude = -0.071948;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.15f;
    [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

One thing you might have to take care of when using `performSelector` is to cancel a pending call if the view is closed or deallocated before the call is scheduled to run.  For example, if the user closes the view two seconds after loading it.  Three seconds later, the scheduled method may still get called but will crash since the view is gone.  To avoid this, cancel any pending performs in `viewWillDisappear:` or wherever appropriate:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```

Comment: in what method do I put the first set region in, currently getting undeclared errors...

Comment: In viewDidLoad, where you already have it.  Just change the span.

Comment: okay, its centering where my annotation is placed, I want the pin to animated placed once my second set region zooms in, currently its happening straight away

Comment: sorted myself :) with help from the code. thanks alot for helping ! :) cannot up vote answer with only 9 rep btw

Comment: only 1 problem, when my second set region loads, my pin annotation is centred but the callout isnt its to the left :S

Comment: Are you calling selectAnnotation at the same time that you do the second setRegion?  Try delaying that also just like you are delaying the second setRegion.  Put the selectAnnotation call in a separate method and schedule it with performSelector in zoomInToMyLocation.  Try a delay of 0.5 or so.  If still issues, start a new question and post the latest code.

Comment: okay thanks I will try that, something I am seeing just as my map starts to zoom, a glitch of some sort, I see a red map pin fly across the top of the screen :S thats not normal ?

Comment: I will update my code with what I put, getting 1 error for the 
'ann.coordinate = region.centre' - of the annotation, see whats up? then if you have no solution, I will post up new question.

Comment: In selectAnnotation, there is no `region` variable declared in that method so the compiler doesn't know what it is.  Either declare your `region` variable as an ivar and set it once in viewDidLoad or re-declare and set it in selectAnnotation.  Also, the map delegate should be set at the start in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0 }, { 0.0, 0.0 } };
region.center.latitude = Your Latitude ;
region.center.longitude = Your Longitude;
region.span.longitudeDelta =  0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta =  0.01f;
[map setRegion:region animated:YES];
[map addAnnotation:ann];
```